# SQL Developer - Using start and end date variables in where clause of my query

Tags: oracle, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that I run everyday that requires a `StartDate` and `EndDate` value.  The `StartDate` and `EndDate` used to be a manual input but I am trying to get away from that and calculate the `StartDate` and `EndDate` to be used in the query.  I've developed code to capture the `StartDate` and `EndDate` in variables:

```
DECLARE

    c_DateMask VARCHAR2(20) := 'DD-Mon-YYYY';
    c_TimeMask VARCHAR2(20) := 'HH24:MI';

    v_Month char(4) := 'Prev'; 
    v_StartDate date; 
    v_EndDate date; 
    v_Environment char(7) := 'Prod';  

BEGIN

    if v_MONTH = 'Prev'
        THEN 
            select TO_DATE ('01-' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1),'mon-yyyy')) into v_StartDate from dual; 
            select Last_day(TO_DATE('01-' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1),'mon-yyyy'))) into v_EndDate from dual;
        ELSE
            select TO_DATE ('01-' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 0),'mon-yyyy')) into v_StartDate from dual;
            CASE
                WHEN v_Environment = 'Prod'
                    THEN
                        -- Production Environment --
                          select 
                              to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-yyyy ') ||
                              case 
                                  when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 00 and 20
                                    then to_char(sysdate, 'hh24')-1||':58'||':00' 
                                  when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 21 and 40
                                    then to_char(sysdate, ' hh24')||':18'||':00' 
                                  when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 41 and 60
                                    then to_char(sysdate, ' hh24')||':38'||':00'
                              END 
                          into v_EndDate from dual;
                WHEN v_Environment = 'OldTest'
                    THEN
                       -- Test Environment --
                            select 
                                to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-yyyy ') ||
                                case 
                                when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 10 and 30
                                    then to_char(sysdate, 'hh24')||':08'||':00'
                                when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 31 and 50
                                    then to_char(sysdate, ' hh24')||':28'||':00' 
                                when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 51 and 60
                                    then to_char(sysdate, ' hh24')||':48'||':00'
                                END 
                            into v_EndDate from dual;
            end case;    
    end if;
```

I then want to use the variables in my select statement below:

```
    -----------------
    /* KPI Figures */
    -----------------

    SELECT 
        SysDate as RunTime
        , v_StartDate
        , v_EndDate
        , TTM_OFF_CONTRIBUTOR
        , SUM(NVL(TTM_PER_OFF_FEE,0)) Fees
    FROM  [Table]
    Where 
        TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    >= v_StartDate
        AND TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    <= v_EndDate
    group by SysDate, v_StartDate, v_EndDate, TTM_OFF_CONTRIBUTOR

END;
```

It all works up until when I try to use the variable values in the KPI Figures query.  What am I missing?

**Update:**

Regarding [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083579/sql-developer-using-start-and-end-date-variables-in-where-clause-of-my-query/4092875#4092875):  I tried but it didn't work and I get the following error:

> `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.`

I am sure I saw another response yesterday which is now gone relating to being able to assign multiple values to variables or something.

Is that what I need and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The variables v_StartDate and v_EndDate are only in scope within the PL/SQL block where they are declared.  It looks like you are then trying to use them outside the block in a separate query.  To do that you will need to create SQL Developer bind variables outside the PL/SQL block like this:

```
var v_start_date varchar2(11)
var v_end_date varchar2(11)
```

Then reference these as bind variables in both the PL/SQL block and the SQL query:

```
declare
  ...
begin
  ....
  :v_start_date := '01-' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1), 'mon-yyyy');
  :v_end_date := TO_CHAR(Last_day(TO_DATE('01-' 
                 || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1),'mon-yyyy'))));
  -- (NB No need to select from dual)
  ...
end;
```

SQL:

```
...
Where 
TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    >= TO_DATE(:v_StartDate)
AND TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    <= TO_DATE(:v_EndDate)
```

Note that these variables cannot be declared with a type of DATE, so they need to be converted back to dates in the query (using the correct format mask).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you wrap the startdate/enddate in two functions (stored procedures)

```
create or replace function get_startdate(p_month in varchar2, p_env in varchar2)
return date
is
  l_return date;
begin
   ... logic goes here ...
   return l_return;
end;
```

Similar for enddate.

Then use those functions in your query:

```
SELECT 
    SysDate as RunTime
    , get_startdate('Prev', 'Prod')
    , get_enddate('Prev', 'Prod')
    , TTM_OFF_CONTRIBUTOR
    , SUM(NVL(TTM_PER_OFF_FEE,0)) Fees
FROM  [Table]
Where 
    TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    >= get_startdate('Prev', 'Prod')
    AND TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    <= get_enddate('Prev', 'Prod')
group by SysDate, get_startdate('Prev', 'Prod'), get_enddate('Prev', 'Prod'), TTM_OFF_CONTRIBUTOR
```

Sidenote: please consider a more concise version to determine first and last day of a month. You also can just assign a value to a variable without using SELECT INTO, e.g.

```
startdate := trunc(sysdate, 'MM'); -- first day of current month
enddate := last_day(trunc(sysdate, 'MM')); -- last day of current month
```

To calculate with hours, you could add/subtract a number of minutes, that's more readable than all the to_date/to_char conversions you do, e.g.

```
enddate := trunc(sysdate, 'HH24');
case 
  when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 00 and 20 then enddate := enddate - 2/(24*60);
  when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 21 and 40 then enddate := enddate + 18/(24*60);
  when to_char(sysdate, 'mi') between 41 and 60 then enddate := enddate + 38/(24*60);
end;
```

Good luck, Martin

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your query and aliases. Try

```
SELECT 
    SysDate as RunTime
    , v_StartDate AS StartDate
    , v_EndDate AS EndDate
    , TTM_OFF_CONTRIBUTOR
    , SUM(NVL(TTM_PER_OFF_FEE,0)) Fees
FROM  [Table]
Where 
    TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    >= v_StartDate
    AND TTM_PROCESSED_DATE    <= v_EndDate
group by RunTime, StartDate, EndDate, TTM_OFF_CONTRIBUTOR
```